# Hide the scrollbar with scrolling enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In the below code I have two blocks, of those I'm maintaining the scroll position of the left block when I scroll the right one. Here I just want to hide the scrollbar of the left block.

Any help would be great.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#two').scroll(function() {
        var bodyScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        $('#one').scrollTop(bodyScrollTop);
    });
});
```

```css
td{
  width:50px;
}
.one, .two{
  height:120px;
  width:200px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
.one{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one" id="one">
  <table border="1">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="two" id="two">
  <table border="1">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3b8y6am2/

Comment: example - https://jsfiddle.net/n9ytpax1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `overflow` property:

```
.one {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Example:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#two').scroll(function(){
  var bodyScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('#one').scrollTop(bodyScrollTop); 
 });
});
```

```css
td{
  width:50px;
}
.one, .two{
  height:120px;
  width:200px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
.one{
  float:left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one" id="one">
  <table border="1">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="two" id="two">
  <table border="1">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, when scrolled on the left block can we make the both blocks scroll.

Comment: Now that's a little bit more difficult. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16670931/283863) which contains several solutions. Beware that some solutions might require vendor specific prefixes such as `-webkit-`. Those will only work in specific browsers (ex `-webkit` will only work in WebKit based browsers including Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox.)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. i will have a look into that!

Answer (score 2):

You can just make overflow-y:hidden for .one class, since you are scrolling it programmatically.

```
.one{
  float:left;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

```js
$(function(){
$('#two').scroll(function(){
  var bodyScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('#one').scrollTop(bodyScrollTop); 
 });
});
```

```css
td{
  width:50px;
}
.one, .two{
  height:120px;
  width:200px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}

.one{
  float:left;
 overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one" id="one">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="two" id="two">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> use this css
>
> `::-webkit-scrollbar {
>           width: 0px;
>           background: transparent; /* make scrollbar transparent */
>       }`

```js
$(function(){
$('#two').scroll(function(){
  var bodyScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('#one').scrollTop(bodyScrollTop); 
 });
});
```

```css
td{
  width:50px;
}
.one, .two{
  height:120px;
  width:200px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
.one{
  float:left;
}
#one::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent; /* make scrollbar transparent */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one" id="one">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="two" id="two">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: What about Firefox, IE and Edge

Comment: Only if the scrollbar is always 20px wide :) which is not always the case

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
    $('#two').scroll(function(){
      var bodyScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
      $('#one').scrollTop(bodyScrollTop); 
            $('#one').css("overflow-y","hidden");
     });
    });
    
   $('#one').hover(function(){
            $('#one').css("overflow-y","auto");
    });
```

```css
td{
      width:50px;
    }
    .one, .two{
      height:120px;
      width:200px;
      overflow-y:auto;
    }
    .one{
      float:left;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="one" id="one">
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

    <div class="two" id="two">
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```